# No image show up on for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, callable

I made a function which creates plotly figure and applied for loop on it.

```
def doplot(df, somenumber):
forplot = some_preprocessing_function(df,somenumber)
fig = px.line(forplot, x = 'STATS_DTTM', y = "FRME_DISTRICT_CODE",color = "FRME_MEDIA", line_group="FRME_MEDIA", hover_name="FRME_MEDIA", line_dash  = 'FRME_MEDIA')

return fig
```

When executing the function without for loop, the function successfully showed an image.

```
doplot(df,0)
```

After I checked the function generates an image, I tried for loop on it so that I can see the output images for different parameters.

```
for i in range(4):
    doplot(df,i)
```

The for loop fail to create any image. I found out that I missed `fig.show()` in my plotting function but I still cannot understand why even the last image did not show up. As I understand, the for loop is same as the code below.

```
doplot(df,0)
doplot(df,1)
doplot(df,2)
doplot(df,3)
```

and execution of above code results the output image of last code `doplot(df,3)`.

If its about the for loop, can someone explain what I misunderstand about it?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using `plt.figure()` in your `doplot()` function like:

```
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def doplot(df, somenumber):
plt.figure()
forplot = some_preprocessing_function(df,somenumber)
fig = px.line(forplot, x = 'STATS_DTTM', y = "FRME_DISTRICT_CODE",color = "FRME_MEDIA", line_group="FRME_MEDIA", hover_name="FRME_MEDIA", line_dash  = 'FRME_MEDIA')

return fig
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Edit(Explanation): So what `matplotlib` does is it creates a new figure when you call it using `plt.line()` or any other plot function. When in for loop, it continues to **override that same figure** till the end of loop and thus you end up with only the final plot instead of multiple plots from for loop. That is the reason why I added `plt.figure()` in the function that will loop so it creates a **new figure every iteration**.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I found out how to solve the problem but still not sure why the image does not pop up when the plot function is in the for loop. My guess is for loop process or jupyter notebook but not sure ;(

Comment: So what `matplotlib` does is it creates a new figure when you call it using `plt.line()` or any other plot function. When in for loop, it continues to ***override that same figure*** till the end of loop and thus you end up with only the final plot instead of multiple plots from for loop. That is the reason why I added `plt.figure()` in the function that will loop so it creates a ***new figure every iteration***.